# Deterministic finite-state automaton in x86 Assembly (GCC)

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, att, dfa

I'm working on a DFA program in Assembly. This is basically a system that reads a binary string and interprets them in the following states, shown in the below image.
[image]

It essentially just shows the even amount of 0's and even amount of 1's in a string. I tried to represent this system with the following program in assembly:

```
.section .data
input_prompt:
asciz "Enter a string of 0s and 1s: "

invalid_message:
.asciz "ERROR: invalid input\n"
EEPrompt:
    .asciz "Input accepted\n"
NotEEPrompt:
    .asciz "Input rejected\n"
newline:
.byte 10

.section .bss
input:
.byte 0
.byte 0  # to store the current character

.section .text
.globl main

main:

# PRINTS INPUT PROMPT
movl $4, %eax            # Writing syscall
movl $1, %ebx            # stdout, prepare for output
lea input_prompt, %ecx   # point to our input prompt
movl $29, %edx           # load our message length
int $0x80                # invoke syscall

movl $0, %ebx            # Initialize our state
lea input, %esi          # points to input buffer

read_loop:
# Read each character with call getchar@PLT
call getchar@PLT
# CHECKS FOR NEW LINE
cmpb $0x0A, %al          #If new line is detected, we are finished.
je input_complete        # End loop

# We need to determine if the character we are processing is a '1' or a '0'
cmpb $0x30, %al          # Compares input with ASCII '0'
jl invalid_input         # If it is less than 0, input is not valid
je zero_entered         # If character IS 0, proceed to jump table
cmpb $0x31, %al          # Compare input with ASCII '1'
jg invalid_input       # If input is greater than 1, input is not valid
je one_entered         # If character IS 1, proceed to jump table

# Store our new and valid input
movb %al, (%esi)         # Store character
inc %esi                # Increment buffer

zero_entered:
# '0' was input
cmpl $0, %eax        # We are in EE. Now, go to OE.
je ee_to_oe
cmpl $1, %eax        # We are in OE. Now, go to EE.
je oe_to_ee
cmpl $2, %eax        # We are in OO. Go to EO
je oo_to_eo
cmpl $3, %eax        # We are in EO. Go to OO.
je eo_to_oo

jmp read_loop

one_entered:
# '1' was input
cmpl $0, %eax        # We are in EE. Now, go to EO
je ee_to_eo
cmpl $1, %eax        # We are in OE. Now, go to OO.
je oe_to_oo
cmpl $2, %eax        # We are in OO. Now, go to OE.
je oo_to_oe
cmpl $3, %eax        # We are in EO. Now, go to EE.
je eo_to_ee

jmp read_loop

ee_to_oe:
movl $1, %eax        # EE to OE
jmp read_loop

oe_to_ee:
movl $0, %eax        # OE to EE
jmp read_loop

oo_to_eo:
movl $3, %eax        # OO to EO
jmp read_loop

eo_to_oo:
movl $2, %eax        # EO to OO
jmp read_loop

ee_to_eo:
movl $3, %eax        # EE to EO
jmp read_loop

oe_to_oo:
movl $2, %eax        # OE to OO
jmp read_loop

oo_to_oe:
movl $1, %eax        # OO to OE
jmp read_loop

eo_to_ee:
movl $0, %eax        # EO to EE
jmp read_loop

invalid_input:
# Invalid Input Detected. Terminate program.

movl $4, %eax            # syscall to write
movl $1, %ebx            # stdout
lea invalid_message, %ecx# point to our invalidity message
movl $29, %edx           # length of our message
int $0x80                # invoke syscall

# Exit with status code 1
movl $1, %eax            # syscall to exit
xor %ebx, %ebx           # status code: 1
int $0x80                # invoke syscall

accepted_input:
# Print a message for ACCEPTED input
movl $4, %eax            # syscall to write
movl $1, %ebx            # stdout
lea EEPrompt, %ecx       # point to our acceptance message
movl $16, %edx           # length of our message
int $0x80                # invoke syscall

# Exit with status code 1
movl $1, %eax            # syscall to exit
xor %ebx, %ebx           # status code: 1
int $0x80                # invoke syscall

rejected_input:
# Print a message for REJECTED input
movl $4, %eax            # syscall to write
movl $1, %ebx            # stdout
lea NotEEPrompt, %ecx    # point to the error message
movl $16, %edx           # message length
int $0x80                # invoke syscall

# Exit with status code 1
movl $1, %eax            # syscall: exit
xor %ebx, %ebx           # status code: 1
int $0x80                # invoke syscall

input_complete:
# Add a newline character to the end of the input
movb $0x0A, (%esi)

# Now, compare the %eax value to see if we are in EE. If 0 is in %eax, we are in EE.

cmpl $0, %eax        # Check to see if we are in EE.
je accepted_input    # IF SO, print our accepted message and exit
jg rejected_input    # IF NOT, print our rejected message and exit

# Exit the program
movl $1, %eax            # syscall: exit
xor %ebx, %ebx           # status code: 0
int $0x80                # invoke syscall
```

However, in my program the output always goes to the "rejected_input" state and I'm not sure why. I'm new to assembly, so I'm unsure if there was a program error, a misconception of how DFA works, or both.

[image]

Comment: Apparently you wanted to use `eax` for the current state. At least three problems with that: 1) you never initialize it to the start 2) `getchar` will overwrite it with the returned character 3) `eax` in general is not preserved across calls even if it were not the return value. Fix: you can use `ebx` which is call preserved  but make sure to initialize it to zero before you start reading.

Comment: Just for the record, a much simpler algorithm could get the same result for a string, no DFA required.  `zero_count = length - one_count`, so you just loop over the string, checking for valid characters and counting matches for `'1'`.  That's one loop with two conditional branches.  (Or the counting of `== '1'` can be branchless.)  Also, since you just want odd/even, you can simplify even more: XOR the ASCII characters and check the low bit.  If it's set, you had an odd number of `'1'`s.  (And `even_zeros = (length & 1) ^ odd_ones`.  But this is an exercise in writing a DFA.